# Adding two GOJS diagram in single page

Tags: gojs

I have a page, with two dropdowns. Whenever a dropdown selection is changed I get the diagram data from database and assign it to `MysavedModel` and then to `Mydiagram`.

This works fine for one diagram, but when i change the second dropdown I am able to get the diagram data from database but `myDiagram1.undoManager.isEnabled = true;` is giving me error as `init()` function is called only once during page load. What can I do to populate second diagram.

Comment: Could you add a code sample that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of sample pages that show more than one diagram.  Besides any page showing a **Palette** or an **Overview** (both of which inherit from **Diagram**), there are samples such as:

- http://gojs.net/latest/samples/classHierarchy.html
- http://gojs.net/latest/samples/icons.html
- http://gojs.net/latest/samples/localView.html
- http://gojs.net/latest/samples/twoDiagrams.html
- http://gojs.net/latest/samples/updateDemo.html (actually 3 diagrams)
- http://gojs.net/latest/samples/visualTree.html
- http://gojs.net/latest/samples/visualTreeGrouping.html

Each of these samples initializes each Diagram and then sets Diagram.model.  You can replace the Diagram.model whenever you want to show a different diagram.